# Prove that a 5 digit even number consisting of distinct even digits can't be a perfect square.

Tags: divisibility, decimal-expansion, perfect-squares

I have no idea how to start, except that I know the last two digits must be $24, 04, 84, 64$.

Comment: It could also be $04$ or $84$, I presume.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes sorry.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The remainder by $3$ is $2+4+6+8+0 \equiv 20 \equiv 2$ (using the divisibility rule mod $3$: it's the digit sum); but all squares have remainder $0$ or $1$ mod $3$.

Comment: I noticed you left “mod” outside of the [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr); you can use `a\equiv b \pmod x` for $a\equiv b \pmod x$.